# How to add onClick event on Android recycler view items?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Android `Recycler View OnClick` event is not working in the code. I can see the `Recycler view grid` but when I am clicking on one item nothing is happening.

Here is my code:

```
public class StaggeredGridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StaggeredGridAdapter.StaggeredGridView> {

private Context context;
private List<Warehouse> warehouses = new ArrayList<Warehouse>();
int size;
public StaggeredGridAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public void addItems(List<Warehouse> response) {
    size = response.size();
    warehouses = response;
}

@Override
public StaggeredGridView onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
    StaggeredGridView staggeredGridView = new StaggeredGridView(layoutView);
    return staggeredGridView;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(StaggeredGridView holder, int position) {
    holder.textView.setText(warehouses.get(position).getFace());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return size;
}

class StaggeredGridView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView textView;

    public StaggeredGridView(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_name);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

}

I inherited inner class i.e. `StaggeredGridView` with `Views.OnClickListner` and debug point is not reaching to `StaggeredGridView.OnClick` method. There is no exception in `ADB logs`.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this simple thing and it will start working with you

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

//add this

```
public StaggeredGridView(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_name);
        staggeredGridView.setOnClickListener(this)

    }
```